# CIUnsharpMask not working?

Tags: ios, core-image

I'm trying to use the CIUnsharpMask filter to process an image. The problem is that the image returned is blank. Nothing comes up in the image view. I've been using the same template for the rest of my filters and they've worked fine. radiusValue and intensityValue are both NSNumbers btw.

```
CIImage *ciUnsharpMaskImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:preFilterImage];
CIContext *ciUnsharpMaskContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
CIFilter *ciUnsharpMaskFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIUnsharpMask" 
                                          keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, ciUnsharpMaskImage, 
                               @"inputRadius", radiusValue,
                                 @"inputIntensity", intensityValue, nil];
CIImage *ciUnsharpMaskOutputImage = [ciUnsharpMaskFilter outputImage];
CGImageRef ciUnsharpMaskCgimg = [ciUnsharpMaskContext 
                                 createCGImage:ciUnsharpMaskOutputImage 
                                 fromRect:[ciUnsharpMaskOutputImage extent]];
preFilterImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ciUnsharpMaskCgimg];
CGImageRelease(ciUnsharpMaskCgimg);
NSLog(@"unsharp mask filter applied");

[self.imageView setImage:preFilterImage];
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I used the following code to get a list of available filteres and CIUnsharpMask isn't one of them :(

```
NSArray *supportedFilters = [CIFilter filterNamesInCategory:kCICategoryBuiltIn];
for (CIFilter *filter in supportedFilters) {
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[CIFilter filterWithName:(NSString *)filter] inputKeys]];
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", filter, string);
}
```

Comment: If you do want to apply an accelerated unsharp mask on iOS, take a look at the GPUImageUnsharpMask filter in my GPUImage framework: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Answer (score 0):

CIUnsharpMask was added to Core Image in iOS 6.